# Gimp: Permanently disable layer boundary lines

Tags: gimp, layers

Trying to get used to Gimp coming from Photoshop. Making progress, but one thing I can't deal with is having that yellow dotted line around selected layers. I know that I can  turn them off in the View menu - but I have to do that for every new image. Is there a way to either completely disable the lines, or set a keyboard shortcut to toggle them off/on?
Thanks

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Maybe worthwhile noting that there is a reason GIMP has a layer boundary. If you disable it, then you won't be able to see where it is. This doesn't matter in Photoshop, as the layers are the same size as the canvas. This isn't always the case in GIMP where you can have layers that are smaller than the canvas. This can lead to all sorts of confusion/potential problems such as for example not being able to paint on pixels outside the layer boundary, and not knowing why.

Answer (score 8):

To **permanently disable** layer boundaries from the *File > Preferences* menu chose *Image Windows > Apearance* to untick *Show layer boundary*. This then works on all newly created layers.

[image]

To toggle visibility of layer boundaries create a **keyboard shortcut** from *Edit > Preferences > Interface*. Select *Configure Keyboard Shortcut* and scroll down to the entry *Show layer boundary*. By default this entry is disabled. After selecting you can assign a not yet otherwise used keyboard shortcut by simply pressing it.

[image]

Comment: Looks like "Preferences" menu has been moved to under "Edit" top menu instead of "File".